# redis - increase or reset based on condition

Tags: redis, conditional-statements, atomic

I would like to increase a value only if a certain key exists. If the key does not exist, the value should be set to 1. Is it possible to implement this logic as an atomic step?

Answer (score 2):

The `INCR` command does exactly what you want.

If the key does NOT exist, the value will be set to 0 before performing the increase operation, i.e. the value will be set to `1`. And the command runs atomically.

**UPDATE**

If the key to be increased is NOT the same key whose existence is checked, you have to write a `Lua` script to do the work in a transaction.

```
if (redis.call("exists", KEYS[1]) > 0) then redis.call("incr", KEYS[2]) end
```

Comment: The key in the condition is not the key of the increased value.

Comment: @nagy.zsolt.hun In that case, there's no built in way to do that, you have to write a Lua script to do the work in a transaction.

Comment: @for_stack regardless, **NEVER** hardcode key names in a script

Comment: @ItamarHaber Thanks for pointing it out, although the code is only for explanation. And I updated the example.

Comment: "only for explanation" is the most dangerous kind - gets copy-pasted like crazy ;)